# Dynamic Multiple Selects & Dynamic Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have a problem where I want the following HTML down below to be looped and summed up into a total. That is working.

However I would also like to be able to:

- output each selected option together with the corresponding label as
  soon as it has been selected and save the values for each selected
  option in each select box

I am having trouble in how I get the corresponding label and slected option per selectbox so that I can use them at a later stage.

for example:
I would like to know:

- what options were selected
- what were the names of the selected options
- what were the values of the selected options
- what was the corresponding label to each    selected option

HTML:

```
<div id = "form">
<form id = "test">    
<label>Label 1/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box1' id='box1' onchange='code(1)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
        <option value='1000'>1000 Text</option>
        <option value='2500'>2500 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 2/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box2' id='box2' onchange='code(2)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
        <option value='1000'>1000 Text</option>
        <option value='2500'>2500 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 3/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box3' id='box3' onchange='code(3)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
        <option value='1000'>1000 Text</option>
        <option value='2500'>2500 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 4/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box4' id='box4' onchange='code(4)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
        <option value='1000'>1000 Text</option>
        <option value='2500'>2500 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 5/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box5' id='box5' onchange='code(5)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
        <option value='1000'>1000 Text</option>
        <option value='7000'>7000 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 6/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box6' id='box6' onchange='code(6)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='300'>300 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 7/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box7' id='box7' onchange='code(7)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Label 8/label>
    <select class='pricebox' name='box8' id='box8' onchange='code(8)'>
        <option value='0'>Choose</option>
        <option value='100'>100 Text</option>
        <option value='250'>250 Text</option>
        <option value='500'>500 Text</option>
        <option value='1000'>1000 Text</option>
        <option value='2500'>2500 Text</option>
    </select>
    <br />
<p id="demo"></p>
</form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function code() { // forget the parameter
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pricebox");
    var names = '';
    var datvalue = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while(i<elements.length) {
        names = elements[i].name;
        elval = parseFloat(elements[i].value);
        datvalue = datvalue + elval;
        i++;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<b>Total: " + datvalue + " SEK</b>";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update your code function with this;

```
// Code goes here
var data = {}

function code() { // forget the parameter
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pricebox");
    var name;
    var id;
    var datvalue = 0;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(item, index) {
      id = item.id;
      name = item.name;
      elval = parseFloat(item.value);
      datvalue = datvalue + elval;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<b>Total: " + datvalue + " SEK</b>";
      data[id] = {
        name: name,
        value: elval
      };
    });
}
```

Than, you can reach your data with global data variable. And you can check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3TRRpETmPnkw4QlNr8X) for seeing what I did. By the way, I have updated the code with a forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, put this:

```
var index = elements[i].selectedIndex;
var options = elements[i].options;

var value = options[index].value
var text  = options[index].text
```

You can store the value, text in an array. I am not great with javascript, so not sure how would you select label. In jquery, I could have just used .parent().prev()

I will look around and update the answer if I find how to.